# Why wp_register_script doesn't work for register_activation_hook

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to register a script using when my plugin is activated. So I placed:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'register_script');

function register_script(){
   wp_register_script('addjs','http://example.com/exmple.js');
}
```

Next I created a meta box and enqueue the script in the `add_meta_boxes` hook:

```
wp_enqueue_script('addjs');
```

Why that doesn't work? My JS file is just a simple `alert` function. However, why when I register my script using `init` hook, or other hook, my code works?

Comment: Because that's not the place to call `wp_register_script`. Why would you want to do it there?

Comment: actually i want to register the script when my plugin is activated

Comment: i just want to understand why it work as i only want to call my wp_register_script once and not everytime the wordpress load with init action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Registering* the script doesn't actually *enqueues* the script. And that's what needs to be optimized.

`register_activation_hook` runs *only once*, registering your script there *won't keep it registered* in subsequent WordPress loads. [Neither the action hook `init`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/24583/12615) is the place to do this. It's either `wp_enqueue_scripts` (frontend) or `admin_print_scripts` (backend), despite their names they're used to enqueue styles and scripts.

Loading your scripts **only** in specific places is a great practice. Once my admin area broke because a theme was loading its scripts/styles *everywhere*, not only on the frontend. [Crappy code](http://crappycode.wordpress.com/) at its best.

The main difference is that if you ***register*** a script, you'll only need to call `wp_enqueue_script($handle)` in other places of your code. But if it's not the case, you can drop the register part and enqueue directly.

A small trick is to add your `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style` **inside** your `add_meta_box()` callback, and it will only load together with the Meta Box. Works the same for Shortcodes.

Another option,

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', function() 
{
    $page = add_submenu_page( $args );
    add_action( "admin_print_scripts-$page", 'your_callback' );
});
```

Or,

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    if( is_single() )
        wp_enqueue_style( $args );
});
```

<sup>*References:

- [conditional-wp-enqueue-script-on-a-page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24580/conditional-wp-enqueue-script-on-a-page)

- [when-to-use-add-actioninit-vs-add-actionwp-enqueue-scripts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55924/when-to-use-add-actioninit-vs-add-actionwp-enqueue-scripts)

- [register-and-enqueue-conditional-browser-specific-javascript-files](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54327/register-and-enqueue-conditional-browser-specific-javascript-files)

- [how-to-load-scripts-and-css-for-admins-only-when-editing-or-adding-posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22354/how-to-load-scripts-and-css-for-admins-only-when-editing-or-adding-posts)*</sup>